# Run IF only once in FOR loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, thumbnails

I am trying to put thumbnails into the Diapo gallery by Pixadelic ([link](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/)), but I am running into one issue. I am using the code below, and I need the IF statement to run only once, as if not, *counter* will stay with value 0 forever, and I want it to start adding 1 each time it loops after applying 0 to its value. Any ideas?

```
if(thumbnails==true) {
        $('#pix_pag').append('<div id="thumb_div"/>');
        var thumbNum;
        var counter;
        for (thumbNum = 0,counter=0; thumbNum < amountSlide; thumbNum++,counter++){ 


            var dataThumb = selector.eq(thumbNum).attr('data-thumb');
            var newImg = new Image();
            newImg.src = dataThumb;
            var leftVal = 25+25*counter;
            var thumbsWidth = $("#pix_pag").width(); 
            var totalVal = 75*(thumbNum+1)+25+25*thumbNum+75;
            var checker = true;

            if(totalVal>=thumbsWidth && checker==true){
                counter=0;
                checker=false;
            }



            $('#thumb_div').append($(newImg).attr({'class':'thumb_nav_'+thumbNum,'style':'position:relative;width:75px;height:75px;top:25px;left:'+leftVal+'px;cursor:pointer;border:solid 1px;box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888;'}));



            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Maybe try explain better, I don't really get it.

Comment: Never mind, it's solved, thanks. Anyway, if it's useful to someone, all I was trying to do was making the IF statement that is in the FOR loop run only once, instead of running everytime the loop started over. To solve it, I just did what Barmar said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `var checker = true;` before the loop. Otherwise, you set it back to `true` each time through the loop, so the test `&& checker == true` will always succeed.